# postgres, how to select where-in and limit N per foreign key?

Tags: postgresql

In my postgres db, I have a posts and comments table:

posts:

```
id  title
1   post1
2   post2
3   post3
```

comments:

```
id  post_id  content
1   1        a   
2   1        b
3   1        c
4   2        d
5   3        e
6   3        f
7   3        g
```

How do I select comments `where post_id in (1,3)`, but limit to 2 per `post_id`, so that I get:

```
id  post_id  content
1   1        a   
2   1        b
5   3        e
6   3        f
```

**EDIT:** For my specific case, I am able to construct the query programmatically by looping through an array of post_ids.

Was thinking:

```
(select * from comments where post_id = 1 limit 2)
union all
(select * from comments where post_id = 3 limit 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY content) rn
    FROM comments
    WHERE post_id IN (1, 3)
)

SELECT id, post_id, content
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join.

```
select foo.* from 
posts 
cross join lateral 
(select * from comments where post_id=posts.id order by content limit 2) foo 
where post_id IN (1, 3);
```

In your question, it is not clear what to order by, so I just copied the order from Tim's answer.  This has the potential to be much faster than the row_number(), as that will number all comments for each relevant post then filter out ones with high numbers.  While the lateral just counts to 2 for each post, then stops.

Comment: I added a missing detail to the original question — I am able to construct the query programatically. Would `union all` be the fastest way?

Comment: If you are selecting only the columns from comments table, then  your `union all` would be faster, since there are no joins.